# How can I call another file to my current one php

Tags: php

```
 require("Remittance.php");

    $id=$_GET['id'];

$remit= new Remittance();
$remit->getById($id);

echo $remit;
```

I have this code, and I just want it to display what the `id` is inside the file from 'Remittance'. However it won't display anything, all I get is a blank page, and I'm not sure what the exact problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require("php_file");

$id=$_GET['id'];

$remit= new php_file();
$id_needed= $remit->getById($id);

echo $id_needed;
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
include 'Remmittee.php';
```

and the URL should be

> www.inactive/test?id=1234

and to get the id, use,

> $_GET['id'];

Comment: Yeah but I need to create an object of my class and then call the function of the object

Answer (score 0):

$_GET['id'];
and include Remmittance